# How to skip jackson timezone correction in spring-mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I want to configure `jackson` to output any date/time values with the following format:

`spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

I'm fetching many database rows and return them just as a `json` map.

```
@RestController
public class MyService {
    @GetMapping
    public List<Map<String, Object>> get(Param params) {
             return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, params);
    }
}
```

Problem: the databases and jvm default timezone is `Europe/Berlin`, thus UTC+2. Therefor jackson automatically converts any database-received `java.sql.Timestamp` to UTC first (subtracts 2 hours), and then outputs them via json.

In the `mysql` database itself, it's a `datetime` type.

But I just want jackson to output the timestamps "as is", without prior conversion! Is that possible to skip timezone correction?

I just want to ignore the timezone without conversation. Just cut it.

Comment: What is your database column datatype? Could you avoid the `Timestamp` class? It is long outdated. It sounds like you should want the `LocalDateTime` datatype from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It doesn’t have a time zone, so should prevent any time zone issues. `Instant` is another option depending on circumstances.

Comment: What's the `mysql` equivalent that I'd have to use in order to automatically obtain a `LocalDateTime` instead of `java.sql.Timestamp`? Indeed currently it's a `mysql datetime` datatype.

Comment: This question might have the answer you are looking for [Jackson Serialization Ignore Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519938/jackson-serialization-ignore-timezone)

Comment: This question is what you need I think.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151633/how-to-make-default-time-zone-apply-in-spring-boot-jackson-date-serialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally it turned out the simples way is to just set the jacksons `ObjectMapper` (which uses `UTC` by defaut) timezone to the jvm defaults:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer init() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            builder.timeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        }
    };
}
```

I'd appreciate if anybody knows how I can achieve the same by just using the `spring.jackson.time-zone` application.property.

Comment: Have you tried annotate the field of `java.util.Date` with `timezone="Europe/Berlin"` in `JsonFormat`?

Comment: Setting a default timezone is not the same as ignoring the timezone

Answer (score 8):

### Approach #1: Setting a default time zone

You could set a time zone in the date format used by [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). It will be used for [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and subclasses:

```java
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
```

In Spring applications, to configure [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), you can do as follows:

```java
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
    return mapper;
}
```

In Spring Boot you can use the property `spring.jackson.time-zone` to define the timezone:

```
spring.jackson.time-zone: Europe/Berlin
```

For more details on the common application properties, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

### Approach #2: Using the Java 8 Date and Time API

Instead of using [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), you could consider [`LocaDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) from the [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). It was introduced in Java 8. The *"local"* date and time classes ([`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)) are not tied to any one locality or time zone. From the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) documentation:

> This class does not store or represent a time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays, combined with the local time as seen on a wall clock. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443004/1426227) will give you more details on the new date and time classes.

Jackson has a module that supports JSR-310 types. Add it to your dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) module in your [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) instance:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Most JSR-310 types will be serialized using a standard [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string representation. If you need a custom format, you can use your own serializer and deserializer implementation. 
See the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) for details.

Comment: Ok that works, but can't I just ignore the timezone? I'm connecting to multiple databases where I don't know the timezone beforehand. And as far as I understood, I'd have to set the databases timezone into the `DateFormat` in your suggestion?

Comment: @membersound If you have different time zones and you deliberately ignore them, won't you have inconsistent results? I have added an alternative approach with `LocalDateTime` to my answer.

Comment: Great answer! If time zone information is relevant, wouldn’t it be better to use a `ZonedDateTime` instead of a `LocalDateTime` or at least a `OffsetDateTome` to account for the time differences between databases solely based on their offsets?

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin in my case I have to work with a legacy database. I just want to output the datetime values "as is" from the database via the json webservice. Any timezone correction is irrelevant, I just want to show the same value via the webservice that exists in the database (and as the mysql `datetime` type is independent of `timezone`, I also want to prevent timezone corrections in java.

Comment: @membersound So attempt to use `LocaDateTime` for that purpose.

Comment: I would **if** I'd create bean fields. But as you can see in my initial question, I'm just returning all columns returned from `jdbctemplate`. And I cannot tell the template to return `LocalDateTime` instead of `java.sql.Timestamp`, could I?

Comment: @membersound [You could try to use a converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37874877/1426227).